# Is the following normal series of $D_n$, $n$ odd, a composition and (or) solvable series?

Tags: group-theory

The series is: $$\langle e \rangle \le \langle b \rangle \le \langle a^2, b \rangle \le D_n.$$

A composition series is where each of the factors are simple. The series is solvable when each of the factors are abelian.

I'm not able to decide if $D_n / \langle a^2, b \rangle$ is simple and (or) abelian. How do you find the order of this quotient group?

Comment: Why do you keep the meaning of $a$ and $b$ a secret? A moment's reflection does point at them likely being standard generators for a dihedral group. Probably $a$ has order $n$ and $b$ has order $2$. Don't assume that your textbook notation is in universal use! Many authors use $r$ and $s$ instead. And many others describe $D_n$ as generated by two reflections.

Comment: Anyway, if I guessed the meaning of $a,b$ correctly I would advice you to check whether $b$ generates a **normal** subgroup of $\langle a^2,b\rangle$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I'm sorry for not being clear. $D_n= \{a^i b^j : 0 \le i < n, j=0, 1 \}$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Why would I need to check if $\langle b \rangle$ is normal in $\langle a^2, b \rangle$ when the series is called a normal series and normality follows from definition?

Comment: I thought the question is partly asking whether this **is** a composition series, but I read carelessly. Anyway, the answer to that is that it is NOT a composition series because $\langle b\rangle$ is NOT a normal subgroup of $\langle a^2,b\rangle$. Also, observe that if $a$ has odd order, then $a$ and $a^2$ generate each other. Please check the question for typos.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh you're right. I'm new to this and I didn't realize I needed to check normality too. In this case, I'm not sure how to prove normality. Again, it would help if I knew how to find the order of the factors, maybe that will help to see if it is normal. How is it not normal?

Comment: Well. There aren't any factors unless the series is normal. Are you sure that there was not $\langle a\rangle$ in place of $\langle b\rangle$, and you copied it incorrectly?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm fairly certain the series above is what our professor wrote in class.

Comment: Then (s)he made a mistake. Anyway, if $n=2k+1$ we have $a=(a^2)^{k+1}\in\langle a^2,b\rangle$, so $\langle a^2,b\rangle=D_n$. Also, $aba^{-1}\notin \langle b\rangle$, so $\langle b \rangle$ is not normal in $\langle a^2,b\rangle$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If we have $\langle a \rangle$ instead, then how do you prove this is a composition and solvable series? And thanks for all your help.

Comment: It's unnecessary to pay attention to the details. This cannot possibly be a composition series for general $n$ because $D_n$ is solvable, so you have to have as many quotients as $|D_n|=2n$ has prime factors, but you only have three.